# How do I correctly use btn-group-justified class applied to input tags

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.3.6. The btn-group-justified class works just fine for link tags, but does not work as I'd expect for input tags. How can I correctly apply the btn-group-justified class in this case?

See example below:

```
<form>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"  id="aaa">
      <a class="btn btn-success" role="">Submit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"  id="bbb">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Output from the html code above]

Comment: Check out , i have added a code snippet @alex

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="submit"]
{
  width:100%!important;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"  id="aaa">
      <a class="btn btn-success" role="">Submit</a>
    </div>
     <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"  id="bbb">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add style="width:100% !important" in your input